# C# JsonConvert - How to parse an irregular key / value JSON?

Tags: c#, jsonconvert

I'm trying to get a json with JsonConvert from a file that contains the following information:

```
 {
  "Programacion": {
    "F201604260700": { "Comercial": "COM63039" },
    "F201604260805": { "Comercial": "COM63039" },
    "F201604260944": { "Comercial": "COM63039" },
    "F201604261113": { "Comercial": "COM63039" }
    }
 }
```

To be able to store the json I have created a class called Tandas, because each "Programming" has a different key ("F201604260700", "F201604260805") I have not managed to create an array of data that works for me

```
public class Tandas
        {
            // Not work
            //public IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, string>> Programacion { get; set; }

            // Not work
            public List<KeyValuePair<string, KeyValuePair<string, string>>> Programacion { get; set; }
        }
```

I do not know much about fixes and objects in C #, what solution could I give?

```
// Error
this.tandas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tandas>(json_tandas_string);
```

Comment: Are the keys in the `{ "Comercial": "COM63039" }` part irregular as well, or do they have a specific format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing JSON dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752345/).

Comment: Hello JLRisge,{ "Commercial": "" } is a regular key

Comment: shouldn't that be an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JsonConvert can deserialize a JSON object to a `Dictionary<string, T>` where `T` is the type of the values.

In this case, the values are also JSON objects, with string values, so `T` in this case would be `Dictionary<string, string>`.

Full class:

```
public class Tandas
{
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> Programacion { get; set; }
}
```

You've now clarified that the inner objects contain regular keys, so you can define a class for that:

```
public class InnerThing
{
    public string Comercial { get; set; }
}

public class Tandas
{
    public Dictionary<string, InnerThing> Programacion { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Amazing! It works and result can be iterated with a foreach, thank you so much!